# Java - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

=>    in this code is there any problem with code or commas or inverted commas
=>    i have import every variable and there is nothing that can i find in this

please tell me where is the problem in this code

```
String inserttable = (
"insert into slam(mobileno , fname , sname , nname , telephone, address, email, bornon, crush, hm, fp, fa, fas, fs, ff, ambition, ayif, impbo, date)" + 
"values ('" + st + "' , '" + a + "' , '" + b + "' , '" + c + "' , " + d + " , '" + e + "' , '" + f + "' , '" + g + "' , '" + h + "' , '" + i + "' , '" + j + "' , '" + k + "' , '" + l + "' , '" + m + "' , '"+ o + "' , '"+ p + "' , '"+ q + "' , '"+ r + "');");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to review the guidelines on asking questions in the Help Center. You need to describe the result you expect and the result you're getting. No one can help you if you don't explain exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your alphabet is missing a letter.

```
'" + l + "' , '" + m + "' , '"+ o + "'
```

Answer (score 2):

You insert 18 values into table with 19 columns